# How can enable HotSpot on android device by delphi code

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

By this delphi code I can enable  wifi on android device.

```
    var    WiFIServiceNative: JWifiManager;
    
    begin
     WiFIServiceNative := 
      JWifiManager.Wrap(TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.WIFI_SERVICE));
     if Assigned(WiFIServiceNative) then
      TJWifiManager.JavaClass.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED
    end;
```

How can enable hotspot  by delphi code.

Comment: I know how to remove a wheel from my car, now how do I change the piston rings?

Comment: @Freddie Bell , If you can't healting my wound, why Sprinkle salt on my wound.

Comment: Because Stack Overflow requires you to show us the code that you did (so far) to solve the problem, not some other piece of code that has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to enable hotspots from code with delphi. for the moment if you need this is the code to open the related menu.

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Intent : JIntent;
NativeComponent : JComponentName;
PackageName:Jstring;
AppName:JString;
begin

PackageName:=StringToJString('com.android.settings');
AppName:=StringToJString('com.android.settings.TetherSettings');

Intent := TJIntent.Create;
Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_MAIN);
Intent.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
NativeComponent := TJComponentName.JavaClass.init(PackageName, AppName);
Intent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);


Intent.setComponent(NativeComponent);
Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) ;
SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);

end;
```

Comment: I want enable and disable hotspot remotely by send command to target App. Your Code don't cover my need.